# xsl:copy-of just the content without the node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a little problem with xsl:copy-of, because I only want to copy the content of the node, not the node itself:

In the XML:

```
<parent>    
    <node>Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</node>
</parent>
```

In the XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:copy-of select="node"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The result:

```
<tr>
    <td><node>Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</node></td>
</tr>
```

The expected result :

```
<tr>
    <td>Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that if I use `xsl:value-of`, I loose the `<b></b>` !!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node/node()" />
```

It looks a bit odd because the element name is also `node` but what the `node()` selector does is select all child elements, text nodes, comment nodes and processing instructions from inside the appropriate node(s) (in this case all child elements called `node` in the current context element).

`node()` does not select attributes, so if you started with

```
<parent>    
    <node attr="foo">Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</node>
</parent>
```

then `<td><xsl:copy-of select="node/node()"/></td>` would produce

```
<td>Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</td>
```

If instead you said `<td><xsl:copy-of select="node/node() | node/@*"/></td>` then you'd get

```
<td attr="foo">Hello, I'm a <b>node</b>!!!</td>
```